# Applying CSS grid in Angular project

Tags: html, css, angular

I designed a webpage, initially using pure HTML and CSS with the Grid Layout.
But then I decided to implement it using Angular.

I've divided the page in basic components (e.g. header, contents, footer) and now I'm trying to transfer the layout. Up until now the page doesn't render as intended.

For example, in the original css file I had the following, which I've tried to move, unsuccessfully, in app.component.css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.item-header {
    grid-area: header;
}
.item-content {
    grid-area: content;
}
.item-footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template:
        "header header header" 70px
        "content content content" auto
        "footer footer footer" 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

So, the main question is: Is there a way to apply a universal CSS Grid Layout that encompasses all components?

Comment: You can import your global css/scss file at `styles` section of `angular.json` file

Comment: Create a https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Thank you Harun!